# How to calculate student pass percentage in excel

Tags: excel

In Excel I have a list of students that do an exam, some of them passed the exam and others are failed.
I want to calculate the pass rate(score) in percentage.
For example 40% of students are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

- count the cells with the value passed,
- divided that through the count of all cells
- format outcome as percentage:

**=countif(B2:B6; "passed")/ counta(B2:B6)**

[image: My example was with dutch excel but worked]

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)** to count the rows having the value 'PASS' and divide it by the **[`total count`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)**. And use `##%` format with **[`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)** function to make it to a percentage value.

**Formula**

```
=TEXT(COUNTIF(A1:An, "PASS") / COUNTA(A1:An), "##%")
```

Now could change the `PASS` value and the column range as per your requirement.

**[Demo](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Atm3yW_VGtlXh3T0ZaYMkByvhVUC)**